# How to compress image in Spring Boot to kb without loosing image quality

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, performance, spring-data

I need some help with image compression. Currently, the requirement is, when we send an email from any mail provider with an inline image attached to that mail, we use to render this email in an editor(Iframe). The problem with this editor is, it does not render that inline-image because I am getting it as CID:****.

What I did is I replace those CID with actual image content. For example, `<img src = data: image type;base64 followed by bytearray>`. This works fine and email also gets rendered in the editor, but problems arise when I send 5 to 10 or even 1 inline image of 10Mb. At that time it takes l0sec to render it (for info, we store email contents in MongoDB).

Is there any good library/code that I can use to compress and also want to resize the image to show in the editor?

Current replace CID to image content code:

```java
private String processInlineHtmlImages(String htmlContent, MimeMessageParser parser, String messageId) throws IOException {
  Collection<String> contentIds = parser.getContentIds();
  if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(contentIds)) {
    for (Iterator<String> contentId = contentIds.iterator(); contentId.hasNext();) {
      String cid = contentId.next();
      String imageContentId = "cid:" + cid;
      if (htmlContent.contains(imageContentId)) {
        DataSource contentIdbyteArray = parser.findAttachmentByCid(cid);
        String imageType = contentIdbyteArray.getContentType() != null ? "jpg" : contentIdbyteArray.getContentType();
        if (contentIdbyteArray != null) {
          ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          try {
            IOUtils.copy(contentIdbyteArray.getInputStream(), outputStream);
          }
          catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("CCM-MessageID: {} exception while processing inline image", messageId);
          }
          byte[] bytes = outputStream.toByteArray();
          // Resize the image if its greater then 1Mb
          if (bytes.length > 1048576) {
                // Compress code should be here if size of bytes more than 1Mb
          }
          StringBuilder imgSrc = new StringBuilder();
          imgSrc.append("data:image/" + imageType + ";base64,");
          imgSrc.append(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes));

          // This will replace the html inline image cid to its bytes
          htmlContent = htmlContent.replaceAll(imageContentId, imgSrc.toString());
        }
      }
    }
    return htmlContent;
  }
  return null;
}
```